# Visual Studio 'Step Into' doesn't work with .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, makefile

I have the files `Main.cpp`, `Tokenizer.hpp`, and `Tokenizer.cpp`. I was trying to debug using Visual Studio 2019, and tried to 'Step Into' a method that is declared in `Tokenizer.hpp` and implemented in `Tokenizer.cpp`, but it didn't work as expected and just jumped over the method without stepping into it. I tried to move the method implementation to `Tokenizer.hpp`, and then it worked as expected and stepped into it when debugging.

I only use Visual Studio 2019 for debugging. The Makefile I use to compile is here:

```
CXX=cl
CXXFLAGS=/Zi
SRCS=Tokenizer.cpp
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.obj)

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) Main.cpp $(OBJS)

%.obj: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    del *.obj
```

The three files I use are here:

```cpp
// Main.cpp
#include "Tokenizer.hpp"
int main() {
    t.GetNextToken(); // Doesn't step into unless I move the
                      // implementation from Tokenizer.cpp to Tokenizer.hpp
}

// Tokenizer.hpp
class Tokenizer {
public:
    int GetNextToken();
};

// Tokenizer.cpp
#include "Tokenizer.hpp"
int Tokenizer::GetNextToken() { /*Do stuff*/ return 0;}
```

Comment: Looks to me that you need to add the `/DEBUG` option to your linker step. But it's an unusual set up so I'm not certain.

Comment: Please show the organization of your project tree

Comment: Everything is in the same folder